# How to not count the duplicates from an user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my current code:

```
words = []
word = input('Word: ')
while word != '':
  words.append(word)
  word = input('Word: ')
print("You know "+ str(len(words)), "unique word(s)!")
```

This is what I need:

> Word: Chat
>
> Word: Chien
>
> Word: Chat
>
> Word: Escargot
>
> Word:
>
> You know 3 unique word(s)!

It is not supposed to count any duplicate words. I'm not sure how to avoid this. Because I have done everything else except this. Is there an easy way, but a simple one?

Comment: Do you want to use [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)?

Comment: A fairly clear question but I think is probably asked elsewhere too.

Comment: @RFlack I think so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/python-removing-duplicates-in-lists

Comment: unrelated: `print('You know', len(set(iter(lambda: input('Word: '), ''))), 'unique word(s)')`

Comment: @Kevin Guan (I'm still finding my way in this place) ... I guess my point is, with no disrespect to the OP, what aren't the Duplicate Police on this one.   Im not at all sure how that works.

Comment: @RFlack Hmm...however this question has a good answer, and it has been accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the word is already in the `words` list using the `in` operator:

```
words = []
word = input('Word: ')
while word != '':
    if word not in words:
        words.append(word)
    word = input('Word: ')
print("You know "+ str(len(words)), "unique word(s)!")
```

This will work well but membership testing is *O(n)* for lists.
Consider using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)s for faster lookup.

It'll be performed implicitly by the `set.add` method ("*Add an element to a set. This has no effect if the element is already present.*")
:

```
words = set()
word = input('Word: ')
while word != '':
    words.add(word)
    word = input('Word: ')
print("You know "+ str(len(words)), "unique word(s)!")
```

---

Note that string formatting is better (and easier) way to format the output:

```
print("You know "+ str(len(words)), "unique word(s)!")
```

can be

```
print("You know {} unique word(s)!".format(len(words)))
```